# Clear cache in Cordova app

Tags: android, cordova

When updating the www-folder of my Android app (using Cordova 3.6.3), the app shows an old cached-version of my www.

If I clear app-data (from Android->Settings->Apps) and run the app, the new updated version of www is shown. This is a big problem when publishing new versions of the app.

How can I force the app to clear the cache when the app is updated (or just every time the app starts)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sencha Architect much so this might not be a solution, but when I've had similar things happen I usually just...

```
cd to/MyApp
cd cordova && cordova platforms rm android
# then
cordova platforms add android
# or 
cd .. && sencha app build native
```

...and let Sencha CMD take care of rebuilding the cordova app. Tho if you have made any changes within the android directory they will be removed.

If you are making the changes within the `cordova/www/` directory then those will reappear.

Answer (score 0):

Further investigation reveals that this was not an Cordova issue. I'm using Sencha Touch (from Sencha Architect) and this is where my problem is right now. I'll keep on digging :)

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?293632-sencha-app-build-package-broken-testing-works&p=1073979

Add these line to .sencha/app/package.properties:

```
enable.deltas=false
enable.cache.manifest=false
build.enable.embedded.manifest=true
```