# Cordova phongap build fails connot find symbol webview

Tags: android, cordova, intellij-idea, npm, phonegap

I have exception in cordova
whenever i do build debug or release to generate apk

Its running on my browser and phone gap application from [phone gap getting started](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/desktop/)

I tried lot of downgrading and upgrading for cordova 
Plus
I tried lot of SDKs and build tools versions.
plus
I tried install un install different versions of cordova and npm

I got many different errors when i try thing for example
[Error 1](https://www.google.jo/search?q=cordova-android:%203.6.4,%20failed%20version%20requirement:%20%3E%3D4.0.0&ei=PPQvWqL_GoHXa-HZi6AG&start=10&sa=N&biw=1366&bih=588)
[Error 2](https://www.google.jo/search?q=Plugin%20doesn%27t%20support%20this%20project%27s%20cordova-android%20version.%20cordova-android%3A%203.6.4&oq=Plugin%20doesn%27t%20support%20this%20project%27s%20cordova-android%20version.%20cordova-android%3A%203.6.4&aqs=chrome..69i57.191j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

My project is kinda old its created 4 years ago . but the last time i created
apk was months ago, i know the problem is because i clicked update in intellij for android repository but cant remember what it was then

Here is the Exception , i dont have the full stack because i already
solved it and posting answer here. (i dont want to break things again)

When i run this

```
cordova build android --debug
```

I get cannot find symbol at **the .plugin  the letter p**

```
new CordovaResourceApi(webView.getContext(), webView.pluginManager)
```

Am posting the answer here , because i solved this twice , and yet i spent
two days debugging ! again to solve again.

**P.S**

Here is reference for what i tried on stackoverflow as well, from
what i get in the output console

**Trust me this will save you lot of googling.**

[Achilles 4.2.0 compilation error - cannot find symbol symbol: class Table location: package info.archinnov.achilles.annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201192/achilles-4-2-0-compilation-error-cannot-find-symbol-symbol-class-table-locati)

[How do I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Android applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271182/how-do-i-set-up-intellij-idea-for-android-applications)

[Phonegap / Cordova - Build Apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452084/phonegap-cordova-build-apk)

[Error cannot find symbol org.apache.cordova.CordovaHttpAuthHandler using InAppBrowser Cordova 5.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484802/error-cannot-find-symbol-org-apache-cordova-cordovahttpauthhandler-using-inappbr)

[Clear cache in Cordova app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141273/clear-cache-in-cordova-app)

[Cordova Web view cache clear in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754884/cordova-web-view-cache-clear-in-android)

[How to force refresh the cached source files upon Ionic build/run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197369/how-to-force-refresh-the-cached-source-files-upon-ionic-build-run)

[Clear PhoneGap Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673691/clear-phonegap-cache)

[Apache Cordova - uninstall globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523539/apache-cordova-uninstall-globally)

[Update cordova plugins in one command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783968/update-cordova-plugins-in-one-command)

[How can I delete all unversioned/ignored files/folders in my working copy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2803823/how-can-i-delete-all-unversioned-ignored-files-folders-in-my-working-copy)

[Cordova Error: Your ios platform does not have Api.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042641/cordova-error-your-ios-platform-does-not-have-api-js)

[Cordova Unable to load platformapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799446/cordova-unable-to-load-platformapi)

[cordova phonegap - How to use android API level 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527902/cordova-phonegap-how-to-use-android-api-level-21)

[Cordova build for android level api 20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35839384/cordova-build-for-android-level-api-20/35870921#35870921)

[Error:(18, 56) error: cannot find symbol variable webView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652943/error18-56-error-cannot-find-symbol-variable-webview)

[Error cannot find symbol org.apache.cordova.CordovaHttpAuthHandler using InAppBrowser Cordova 5.3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34484802/error-cannot-find-symbol-org-apache-cordova-cordovahttpauthhandler-using-inappbr)

[Cordova Android project doesn't compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877109/cordova-android-project-doesnt-compile)

[Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42950169/android-sdk-not-found-make-sure-that-it-is-installed-if-it-is-not-at-the-defau)

[How to check the Android developer tools version from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447687/how-to-check-the-android-developer-tools-version-from-the-command-line)

[How to downgrade my SDK Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555337/how-to-downgrade-my-sdk-version)

[Cordova App - build tool error - Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35112884/cordova-app-build-tool-error-gradle)

[How to install Android SDK Build Tools on the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line)

[Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 4.1.1, failed version requirement: >=5.0.0-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921935/plugin-doesnt-support-this-projects-cordova-android-version-cordova-android)

[Can't add crosswalk with ionic cli 1.3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134884/cant-add-crosswalk-with-ionic-cli-1-3-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In My case i had the following:** and i have below what my android manager looked like ( FYI i had to down grade to adapt legacy phone gap that was created long ago !)

C:\work\sajilni_mobile\android>**cordova --version
4.0.0**

C:\work\sajilni_mobile\android>**npm --version
3.10.10**

C:\work\sajilni_mobile\android>**cordova platform list**
Installed platforms: **android 3.6.4**, browser 4.1.0
Available platforms: amazon-fireos, blackberry10, firefoxos, windows, windows8, wp8.

**===>>> And here is my plugins that is working with that.**

> ```
> cordova plugin ls
> com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner 2.0.1 "BarcodeScanner"
> cordova-plugin-media 2.4.0 "Media"
> org.apache.cordova.battery-status 0.2.12 "Battery"
> org.apache.cordova.camera 0.3.5 "Camera"
> org.apache.cordova.console 0.2.13 "Console"
> org.apache.cordova.device 0.3.0 "Device"
> org.apache.cordova.device-motion 0.2.11 "Device Motion"
> org.apache.cordova.device-orientation 0.3.11 "Device Orientation"
> org.apache.cordova.dialogs 0.3.0 "Notification"
> org.apache.cordova.file 1.1.0 "File"
> org.apache.cordova.geolocation 0.3.12 "Geolocation"
> org.apache.cordova.media 0.2.16 "Media"
> org.apache.cordova.media-capture 0.3.6 "Capture"
> org.apache.cordova.network-information 0.2.15 "Network Information"
> org.apache.cordova.splashscreen 1.0.0 "Splashscreen"
> org.apache.cordova.vibration 0.3.13 "Vibration"
> ```

FYI cordova build android **--debug**
works but **--release** do not work
In my case i mean )).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes sure, sorry am super busy i will get back and improve it for sure thankx its gona be really beatifull answer i always care about that ))